# Closeable, non thread safe resource in a servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

If I have

1. a `Closeable` resource
2. expensive to create
3. not a `DataSource`
4. which is not thread-safe
5. to be used in servlets
6. and would like to avoid wrapping the resource object it into thread safe access,

what are my options?

First I thought about using `ThreadLocal`, but neither `ThreadLocal` nor `Thread` seem to provide notification when the thread dies. The servlet api provides lots of life-cycle methods, but not for threads.

How is this normally done?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to re-use the resource across multiple requests? Are you allowed you create multiple instances of the resource?

Comment: Twice 'yes'. It is comparatively expensive to create the resource, but have one per thread open is no big deal. And yes, re-using for many requests is not problem too, as long as the resource is only used by one thread at a time.

Comment: Several answers recommend using a resource pool, with Apache pool being one example implementation. Given that I asked how this is "normally done", these are good answers. Yet I was hoping for a solution that does *not* require the client classes to obtain and in particular hand back the acquired resource, because while this pattern is completely standard in programming, it also is a great source for bugs. Still cannot let go of the `ThreadLocal` idea, but I will possibly create a new question with more focus on it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answers to the clarifying questions I've asked, I'd recommend developing a resource pool, similar to the connection pool. The main use cases will be:

1. Create a resource pool at the application startup. The size of the pool should be set to the max number of the exec threads. The result is a pool of available resources.
2. Check out a resource from the resource pool. The result is a resource that the current thread can use without being concerned about multi-threading issues.
3. Use the resource pool while processing a request.
4. Check in the resource back to the pool. The result is the resource being available for check out by other threads.
5. Destroy the resource pool.

There is already a generic resource pool API from Apache that you can use to implement this functionality, [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the nature of the resource...

If it were a Datasource, the management (opening and closing) should not be that of the servlets - it should be the container.

Other resources might be better suited to having a single instance per servlet, so there is no concern over thread safety.

Without further information, I can only suggest that the servlets don't sound like they should be responsible for resource management. Perhaps you could declare a Servlet Context listener that creates the resource when the application starts and closes it when the application stops?

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html

Comment: No datasource, I should have mentioned it for completeness. One instance per servlet is exactly what I would like to avoid. Forgot to mention that it is expensive to create, see edit.

Comment: When do you wish to initialise and clean up the resource? Will ServletContext listener solve your problem?

Comment: no I don't think so, since I don't think that the live-cycle of ServletContextListener matches the live-cycle of threads used to run servlets.

Comment: It might help if you describe the resource and it's desired lifecycle. The threads that service the Servlets are provided by the Container. In all probability they are created at startup and are pooled and reused by the container for the lifetime of the Container. When the app is stopped, the thread pool will be closed and the listener will be informed and the resource can be closed. If you are not happy to use synchronisation to ensure that a resource is safely closed, you need to open and close it outside of the threads!

Comment: Maybe I should not have mentioned 'servlet', because I am interested in the more general problem. But even for a servlet container: is it a guarantee, that threads are all created when the app is started an only stopped when the app get killed. I would think this depends on the thread pool implementation and configuration used whereby long unused threads may be decommissioned by the container.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution available:
Use an object pool. Apache Commons provides a simple implementation that should fit your requirements (see example [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/examples.html)).
The idea is to have a pool manage your objects.
An object can be request, used and then returned. You could acquire an instance at the begin of a request and return it back to the pool at the end.
This is how database-connection-pools are doing it.